# get the activity ovject within action listener

Tags: android

Is there a way to get a pointer of activity which containing object of action Listener?

code snippet:

```
public class ActivityAsContainer exteneds Activity{
    public static ActivityAsContainer _brokeTheAbstractBarier;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _brokeTheAbstractBarier = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.SomeBigLie);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            brokeTheAbstractBarier.dance;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to pass the activity over to the action listener, then use a static global that could break if the object is created twice, and could a view be created twice and still live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
ActivityAsContainer.this
```

e.g

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ActivityAsContainer.this.dance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should not be static.

You can use this definition in `OnCreate` and then use `myActivity` in the listener.

`final Activity myActivity=this;`

Answer (score 1):

Hope you will be able to solve  after using this line

```
  _brokeTheAbstractBarier = YoursMainActivity.this;
```

instead of

```
 _brokeTheAbstractBarier = this;
```

or you can use

```
ActivityAsContainer.this
```

which is

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ActivityAsContainer.this.dance;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of my answer